# how to select surnames where surname equals input

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

im wondering how i would be able to write SQL using pyodbc:

This would be what i would want to write in SQL:

```
SELECT last_name FROM money_spent
WHERE last_name = (surnamereq)
```

But im using pyodbc and ive got this:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT last_name FROM money_spent WHERE last_name = (surnamereq)')
```

and since i cant just go onto the next line and do it like in SQL than i dont know how to.

This is what i want to work:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT last_name FROM money_spent
WHERE last_name = (surnamereq)')
```

But yeah, any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `cursor.execute("""SELECT last_name FROM money_spent
WHERE last_name = (surnamereq)""")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a parameterized query, like so:

```
surnamereq = 'Thompson'
cursor.execute("SELECT last_name FROM money_spent WHERE last_name = ?", surnamereq)
```